# Clang >= 3.3 in c++1y mode cannot parse <cstdio> header

Tags: c++, c++11, header, clang, c++14

I have a project that correctly compiles and runs under g++ 4.8.1 and clang >= 3.3 in c++11 mode. However, when I switch to the experimental `-std=c++1y` mode, clang 3.3 (but not g++) chokes on the `<cstdio>` header that is indirectly included by way of Boost.Test (so I cannot easily change it myself)

```
// /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdio
#include <stdio.h>

// Get rid of those macros defined in <stdio.h> in lieu of real functions.
// ...
#undef gets
// ...    

namespace std
{
// ...
using ::gets; // <-- error with clang++ -std=c++1y
// ...
}
```

with the following error message:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/cstdio:119:11:
>   error: no member named 'gets' in the global namespace

On [this tutorial](https://earthserver.com/Setting_up_a_modern_C++_development_environment_on_Linux_with_Clang_and_Emacs#Disable_max_align_t_when_clang_is_being_used%3a) on how to set up a modern C++ environment, a similar lookup problem with `max_align_t` is encountered. The recommendation there is to use a sed script to surround the unknown symbols with `#ifdef __clang__` macros, but that seems a fragile approach.

Setup: plain 64-bit Linux Mint 15 with

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~13.04) 4.8.1
>
> Ubuntu clang version 3.3-3~raring1 (branches/release_33) (based on
>   LLVM 3.3)

**Questions**:

- what is causing this erorr? There is no `__clang__` macro anywhere near the code in question, and clang in c++11 mode has no trouble at all.
- Is it a language problem (does C++14 say something else than C++11 about importing C compatible symbols from the global into the `std` namespace)?
- Do I need to change something with my include paths? (I use CMake to automatically select the header paths, and switch modes inside CMakeLists.txt)
- Does clang have a switch to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like you have a broken `stdio.h`.  Perhaps reinstall the package that contains such standard header files?

Comment: ooo, it's not broken, it's been updated to C11.

Comment: Also see [LLVM Issue 30277: Clang 3.6 cannot compile program with -std=c++14](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30277) and [Ubuntu Issue 1620181: Clang 3.6 cannot compile program with -std=c++14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1620181) on Launchpad.

Comment: Also see section ***C.3.4 - Removal of std::gets*** at [What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980931/608639)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This note in the `gets` manpage looks relevant:

> ISO C11 removes the specification of gets() from the C language, and since version 2.16, glibc header files don't expose the function declaration if the `_ISOC11_SOURCE` feature test macro is defined.

Probably should be

```
#if !_ISOC11_SOURCE
using ::gets;
#endif
```

Comment: Or test if __cplusplus is strictly more than that of C++11, since glibc assumes that gets won't be in C++14 (not clear yet).

Comment: @MarcGlisse do you know if there is any version of glibc that has such a macro test already? I'm asking because this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=776bf23db41af3414d2e28f342ef65da-5e316e07ec27fc464f163e0f41ec1258) works fine, and even though I have the same clang version, I do get an error, so I'm guessing my headers are messed up somehow.

Comment: I think the simplest way is to *downgrade* glibc to 2.15 (Linux Mint 15 comes with 2.17), which could also explain why the Coliru site has not problems as it is based on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, which has 2.15

Comment: Yes there is, did you check your `stdio.h`? 2.17 has `#if !defined __USE_ISOC11 || (defined __cplusplus && __cplusplus <= 201103L)`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, my `stdio.h` indeed had that. But unless `cstdio` also gets such a macro, it won't build under `clang++ -std=c++1y`. I simply downgraded the glibc to 2.15 and now it works.

Comment: `cstdio` from libstdc++ tests `#if __cplusplus <= 201103L` in gcc-4.9 (can't easily check 4.8 right now).

Comment: See http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13566 and http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51785 for some of the history

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for the links. So the two acceptable solutions are that either glibc and libstdc++ both have a `#ifdef` around `gets`, or they both unconditionally declare it. Is there any chance of backporting the 4.9 fix to 4.8?

Comment: @JonathanWakely not sure if you coordinate at all with libc++, but FYI, [a similar thread on the Clang mailinglist](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/libc-gets-removed-from-C11-td4032945.html)

Comment: Also see [LLVM Issue 30277: Clang 3.6 cannot compile program with -std=c++14](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30277) and [Ubuntu Issue 1620181: Clang 3.6 cannot compile program with -std=c++14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1620181) on Launchpad.

Comment: Also see section ***C.3.4 - Removal of std::gets*** at [What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980931/608639)