# What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, c++-faq

**Introduction**

With the *C++14* (aka. *C++1y*) Standard in a state close to being final, programmers must ask themselves about backwards compatibility, and issues related to such.

---

**The question**

In the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23047198/1090079) it is stated that the Standard has an *Appendix* dedicated to information regarding changes between revisions.

It would be helpful if these potential issues in the previously mentioned *Appendix* could be explained, perhaps with the help of any formal documents related to what is mentioned there.

- *According to the Standard*: What changes introduced in *C++14* can potentially break a program written in C++11?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

> <sup>**Note**: In this post I consider a "*breaking change*" to be either, or both, of;</sup>
>
>    <sup>1. a change that will make legal *C++11* ill-formed when compiled as *C++14*, and;
>
>  2. a change that will change the runtime behavior when compiled as *C++14*, vs *C++11*.</sup>

---

## *C++11* vs *C++14*, what does the Standard say?

The Standard draft ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) has a section dedicated for just this kind of information, where it describes the (potentially breaking) differences between one revision of the standard, and another.

This post has used that section, `[diff.cpp11]`, as a base for a semi-elaborate discussion regarding the changes that could affect code written for *C++11*, but compiled as *C++14*.

---

### C.3.1] Digit Separators

The digit separator was introduced so that one could, in a more readable manner, write numeric literals and write them we normally do (outside of code).

```
int x = 10000000;   // (1)
int y = 10'000'000; // (2), C++14
```

<sup>It's easy to see that *(2)* is much easier to read than *(1)* in the above snippet, while both initializers have the same value.</sup>

The potential issue regarding this feature is that the *single-quote* always denoted the start/end of a *character-literal* in *C++11*, but in *C++14* a *single-quote* can either be surrounding a *character-literal*, or used in the previously shown manner *(2)*.

**Example Snippet, legal in both *C++11* and *C++14*, but with different behavior.**

```
#define M(x, ...) __VA_ARGS__

int a[] = { M(1'2, 3'4, 5) };

// int a[] = { 5 };        <-- C++11
// int a[] = { 3'4, 5 };   <-- C++14
//                              ^-- semantically equivalent to `{ 34, 5 }`
```

( Note: More information regarding *single-quotes* as digit separators can be found in [n3781.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf) )

---

### C.3.2] Sized Deallocation

*C++14* introduces the opportunity to declare a global overload of `operator delete` suitable for *sized deallocation*, something which wasn't possible in *C++11*.

However, the Standard also mandates that a developer cannot declare just one of the two related functions below, it must declare either **none**, or **both**; which is stated in *[new.delete.single]p11*.

```
void operator delete (void*) noexcept;
void operator delete (void*, std::size_t) noexcept; // sized deallocation
```

Further information regarding the potential problem:

> > Existing programs that redefine the global unsized version do not also
> > define the sized version. When an implementation introduces a sized
> > version, the replacement would be incomplete and it is likely that
> > programs would call the implementation-provided sized deallocator on
> > objects allocated with the programmer-provided allocator.
> >
> > <sup>**Note**: Quote taken from [n3536 - C++ Sized Deallocation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3536.html#Compatibility)</sup>

( Note: More of interest is available in the paper titled [n3536 - C++ Sized Deallocation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3536.html), written by *Lawrence Crowl* )

---

### C.3.3] `constexpr` member-functions, no longer implicitly `const`

There are many changes to *constexpr* in C++14, but the only change that will change semantics between *C++11*, and *C++14* is the *constantness* of a *member-function* marked as *constexpr*.

The rationale behind this change is to allow *constexpr* *member-functions* to mutate the object to which they belong, something which is allowed due to the [relaxation of *constexpr*](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html).

```
struct A { constexpr int func (); };

// struct A { constexpr int func () const; }; <-- C++11
// struct A { constexpr int func ();       }; <-- C++14
```

Recommended material on this change, and why it is important enough to introduce potential code-breakage:

- [**Andrzej's C++ blog** - “constexpr” function is not “const”](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/)
- [**open-std.org** - constexpr member functions and implicit const](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3598.html)
- [(**open-std.org** - Relaxing constraints on constexpr functions)](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html)

**Example snippet, legal in both *C++11* and *C++14*, but with different behavior**

```
struct Obj {
  constexpr int func (int) {
    return 1;
  }

  constexpr int func (float) const {
    return 2;
  }
};
```

```
Obj const a = {}; 
int const x = a.func (123);

// int const x = 1;   <-- C++11
// int const x = 2;   <-- C++14
```

---

### C.3.4] Removal of `std::gets`

[`std::gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets) has been [removed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3770.html#GB9) from the Standard Library because it is [considered dangerous](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1194.htm).

The implications of this is of course that trying to compile code written for C++11, in C++14, where such a function is used will most likely just fail to compile.

( Note: there are ways of writing [code](http://codepad.org/ZxyMmP6C) that doesn't fail to compile, and have different behavior, that depends on the removal of `std::gets` from the *Standard Library* )

Comment: Another change is the type of  `auto i{1};`

Comment: @JonathanWakely `std::is_same<decltype(i), std::initializer_list<int>>::value` having `auto i {1}`, will yield `true` in *C++14* too; there has been no change in this aspect.

Comment: Yet another change is [the adding `std::decay` to the implementation of `std::common_type`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975812/should-stdcommon-type-use-stddecay). So the code like `std::common_type<int&, int&>::type f(int& x){return x;}  /*...*/ int x{}; f(x) = 2;` becomes invalid.

Comment: The `common_type` change is a DR, so most vendors will change their C++11 library too (if they haven't done so already) and you won't be able to detect any difference between C++11 and C++14 in that regard.

Comment: Your example for digit separators is not valid C++11, your macro requires more than one argument, [cpp.replace] p4

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, you are right, of course. But the question is about the *potential* possibility of C++11 program breaking.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that particular example is taken straight from [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf), I'll edit the post to make it legal according to `[cpp.replace]p4`. Unless there's an active DR on the matter, there should be, see; `[diff.cpp11.lex]`.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp, oh dear, thanks for the heads-up! I've opened https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/306

Comment: @Constructor, in that case you could list almost every DR resolved since C++11 was published

Comment: Note as I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23415662/1708801) the latest draft is `N3936` and since `N3937` is the C++14 DIS it probably makes more sense to reference that instead.

Comment: That last one is already causing problems with C++1y semi-implementations that are a combination of C11 and C++11 headers, where the latter invokes `std::gets` in the former that no longer exists: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17775390/560648

Comment: For a pathological case, SFINAE can be used to make almost **any** addition to an interface in C++1y a breaking change.  As an example, `template<typename T, typename=typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< void(), decltype( cbegin(std::declval<T>()) ) >::value >::type> void foo(T) { std::cout << "hello "; } template<class...Ts> void foo(Ts...&&) { std::cout << "world"; } int main() { foo( std::vector<int>{} ); foo( 3 ); std::cout << "\n" }` prints `hello world` in C++14, but `worldworld` in C++11 (if I wrote that right): the lack of an interface can make code compile/run in C++ easily.

Comment: @Yakk: That isn't a "breaking" change, though.  The behavior is correctly varying based on the presence of the feature it's designed to detect.

Comment: @benvoigt except I can make valid compiling C++11 programs fail to compile, or crash, in C++1y with it.  You may read intent into the check, except under C++11 it was a constant 'never'.