# Macro for generalized lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I would like to use the generalized lambda capture introduced in C++14 (see [Move capture in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda) for an explanation). However, the remainder of my code is C++11-friendly. I would like to do something along the lines of

```
#ifdef CPP14
// move capture in lambda
#else
// capture by-value
#endif
```

However, there are no good cross-compiler flags to infer versions. Is there anything anyone can suggest? (other than, of course, defining my own macros)

Comment: Perhaps related: [What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980931/1708801) and [Can C++ code be valid in both C++03 and C++11 but do different things?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047198/can-c-code-be-valid-in-both-c03-and-c11-but-do-different-things/23063914#23063914)

Comment: GCC apparently has this as a GNU extension. I think Boost.Phoenix has this as well.

Comment: "there are no good cross-compiler flags to infer versions" - there's always the value of `__cplusplus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually T.C. is right, the C++11 FDIS says in ["16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]"](http://timepp.drivehq.com/cpp11/data/cpp.predefined.html#fn160) that

> The name __cplusplus is **defined to the value 201103L** when compiling a C++ translation unit.

The footnote states:

> It is intended that **future versions of this standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value**. Non-conforming com- pilers should use a value with at most five decimal digits.

So going with the following code seems totally legit to me.

```
#if __cplusplus > 201103L
//c++1y or above
#else
//c++11 or below
#endif
```

However, some compiler might not follow the standard and you might want to check if the `_cplusplus` value has been incremented for c++1y.

The GCC, for example, had this flag set to 1 until the version 4.7.0.

If you need more information on the `_cplusplus` flag, you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)