# What changes between C++98 and C++11 show difference in behavior?

Tags: c++11, language-lawyer, c++98

I was reading the following post:

- [What changes introduced in C++14 can potentially break a program written in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980929/what-changes-introduced-in-c14-can-potentially-break-a-program-written-in-c1)

and also the isocpp page:

- https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html

So I became curious, according to the Standard: What changes introduced in C++11 can potentially break a program written in C++98?

Comment: Some interesting cases here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11 I thought I had a good example, but it was based on *implicit int* that was never formally carried over to C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big one that stands out -- throwing exceptions from destructors.

In C++98 you can have programs that do this and work fine if you are careful.

In C++11 you will often have to explicitly declare the dtor `noexcept(false)`.

Nice [blog post here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/noexcept-destructors/), on Andrzej's C++ blog.

> In short, the following program used to run successfully in C++03 (under some definition of “success”):
>
> ```
> struct S
> {
>   ~S() { throw runtime_error(""); } // bad, but acceptable
> }; 
>
> int main()
> {
>   try { S s; }
>   catch (...) {
>     cerr << "exception occurred";
>   } 
>   cout << "success";
> }
> ```
>
> In C++11, the same program will trigger the call to `std::terminate`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another case related to destructors are noexcept(true) in C++11:

```
// A simple program that demonstrates how C++11 and pthread_cancel don't play
// nicely together.
//
// If you build without C++11 support (g++ threadkill.cpp -lpthread), the
// application will work as expected. After 5 seconds, main() will cancel the
// thread it created and the program will successfully exit.
//
// If you build with C++11 support(g++ -std=c++11 threadkill.cpp -lpthread),
// the program will crash because the abi::__forced_unwind exception will
// escape the destructor, which is implicitly marked as noexcept(true) in
// C++11. If you mark the destructor as noexcept(false), the program does 
// not crash.
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

class sleepyDestructorObject
{
public:
    ~sleepyDestructorObject() //noexcept(false)
    {
        std::cout << "sleepy destructor invoked" << std::endl;
        while(true)
        {
            std::cout << "." << std::flush;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
};

void* threadFunc( void* lpParam )
{
    sleepyDestructorObject sleepy;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t tThreadID;
    pthread_create(&tThreadID, NULL, threadFunc, NULL);
    sleep(5);
    pthread_cancel(tThreadID);
    pthread_join(tThreadID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Original reference:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00036.html